# How do I get VS2012 to autoformat Javascript comment blocks like C# comments

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2012 to auto-format my comment blocks like it does for my C# blocks.  I want my comments to look like this:

```
/*
 * Here is my C# comment block
 * As I type, more [space]*[space] chars are prefixed to every new line
 */
```

But instead I get this:

```
/*
Here is my javascript comment block
Where are my asterisks?  :(
*/
```

It's aggravating that I can't define this behaviour in the Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript menu.  I've got the Web Essentials extension, but it does not automatically help format my comment blocks.  I've also tried editing within an HTML page < script > node, but it doesn't work there either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about write a new snippet file?
Here is a website, but it's in Chinese.
[How to wirte a new snippet file in Visual Studio](http://jingyan.baidu.com/article/ea24bc39b86ededa62b3311f.html)